# jquery mobile gmap3 map not drawing correctly

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have gmap3 in my jquery mobile application (phonegap for Android). Initially when the map is shown it appears not fully drawn on screen of the device. It requires some UI event (press/screen orientation change etc.) in order to draw completely. Any suggestions how to simulate such UI event? Thanks a lot for any directions/ideas!

Comment: I tried reloading the page that contains the map, @shanabus. $('#mappage').trigger('refresh');. Did not cause the map to reload.

Comment: I tried resizing the map element to cause it to redraw $('#map').bind('pageshow', function () {
                                            $('#themap').css({marginTop: size,width:320,height:480}).gmap3('resize');                         
                                    });

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. The map is part of application with multiple pages and since the map was not the first page to load it appeared off centered. I put first page and it loads OK.

Comment: Exactly what was happening in my case, why isn't there any vote up to this answer. Great!!